# Raising onClick events in C# WebBrowser doesn't work

Tags: c#, html, web-scraping

I'm creating a simple web-**scraper**. I want it to download data from a specific webpage. However, the data I want appears after clicking on a div. I'm trying to find that div, invoke click event on it, and then download the page source (after showing the hidden data). The data probably appears on the page after a javascript executes. I had to set WebBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed to true, because too many errors would pop up. Currently I'm using the following code:

```
        WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
        //Navigate etc...

        foreach (HtmlElement el in browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div"))
        {
             if (el.GetAttribute("className").ToString().Equals(className))
             {
                  el.InvokeMember("click");
                  foreach(HtmlElement child in el.Children)
                  {
                      child.InvokeMember("click");
                  }                  
             }
        }

        browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("body")[0].InvokeMember("click");

        while (browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
            Debug.WriteLine("State: " + browser.ReadyState);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
        }

        string source = browser.DocumentText;
```

This doesn't work. The hidden data isn't shown. I've tried using RaiseEvent instead of InvokeMember, and changing click to onclick. Nothing worked.
Btw. the code invokes click on every child, because I'm not sure which one makes the data appear.
Does anyone know what goes wrong?

Comment: Do you know that `child.InvokeMember("click");` ever runs?  Even if you get the code to run it might fail because of all the script errors you've suppressed.  Also, to find the right child you can try right-click and Inspect in Chrome.

Comment: @Dave S I know that it runs from debugger. I tried finding it using Inspect, but there are a lot of similar elements, and it's not really clear which one actually shows the hidden stuff